# putenv/setenv using substitutions

Tags: c

I need user to define all the environment variables needed for my program in a text file as shown below.

MyDLLPath = C:\MyDLLPath
MyOption = Option1
PATH = %MyDLLPath%;%PATH%;

In my program I read each line and call putenv with the string. Problem is that the environment substitutions (%MyDLLPath%) are not being expanded. I am guessing the following fix for that

- Check each line for % characters.
- Get the text between 2 consecutive % characters.
- Call getenv using the text
- Replace value obtained above into the line and then call putenv.

Is there a better way to do it?

Edit: Starting with windows platform. Will have to do unix but not sure how to deal with unix syntax for the substitutions.

Comment: I suppose you're working on a Unix environment?

Comment: No, that's definitely Windows, using backslashes and percent characters.

Comment: The problem with this post is that we're not sure which environment you're developing in. Could you please give us some more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265.aspx).

Comment: +1, could work.  Critically depends on the order in the file though.

Comment: Yes, the order is important, just like in the OP's algorithm. If you wanted the entries in arbitrary order, you'd have to build up a dependency graph; that would probably be overkill for a simple configuration file.